# Excel - Select absolute range in excel with Range property

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying files (cell list) from source to destination folder. I need to select all values from a column in excel in the form of ($A1).

**My code:**

```
Sub SourcetoDestination()

    Dim rngFile As Range, cel As Range        
    Dim desPath As String, filename As String

    Set rngFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").**Range("$A1")** 'assuming file list in ColA

    desPath = "C:Destination\" 

    For Each cel In rngFile

        If Dir(cel) <> "" Then
            filename = Dir(cel) 

            FileCopy cel, desPath & filename 'copy to folder

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

**Problem:**

My code only copy first value from the list.
if I specify range like this :

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1","A3")
```

It works but I want to save absolute range in excel.

Could someone please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need??:

```
Sub SourcetoDestination()
    Dim rngFile As Range, cel As Range
    Dim desPath As String, filename As String
    Dim N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("$A1:$A" & N) 'assuming file list in ColA
    desPath = "C:Destination\"
    For Each cel In rngFile
        If Dir(cel) <> "" Then filename = Dir(cel)
            FileCopy cel, desPath & filename 'copy to folder
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

***UNTESTED***

Comment: Thanks this is exactly I need.